# Reading information from file where multiple lines belong together

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a file formatted like this:

```
Jeff 
22 6 Bridges
John Walthers
31 1 Travolta
George
12 6 Michaels
```

I want to create a class, where each instance has a name ("Jeff" for example) and a birthday and a surname in the line beneath it. So John Walters would be an instance with its variables and Jeff would be another instance.

I just don't get how I have to read the data from the file.

I would just do something like this(if it worked):

```
class Person{

private:
std::string name1, name2;
int i1, i2;

public:
Person(){}

Person(std::string ss1, std::string ss2, int ii1, int ii2)
{
    name1 = ss1;
    name2 = ss2;
    i1 = ii1;
    i2 = ii2;
}

void show()
{
    std::cout << name1 << ", " << name2 << " , " << i1 <<std::endl;
}

void init(std::string ss1, std::string ss2, int ii1, int ii2)
{
    name1 = ss1;
    name2 = ss2;
    i1 = ii1;
    i2 = ii2;
}

bool operator < (const Person& other) const
{
 return (name1 < other.name1 );
}

};


int main()
{
    std::string s1, s2;
    int i1, i2;
    std::set<Person> Personenset;
    std::vector<Person> Personenvec;
    Person p;
    std::ifstream istr("datenprobieren.dat");
    while(istr)
    {   
        getline(istr, s1);
        istr >> i1 >> i2 >> s2; 
        p.init(s1, s2, i1, i2);
        Personenset.insert(p);
        Personenvec.push_back(p);

    }
    std::cout << Personenvec.size() <<std::endl;
    Personenvec[1].show();

    return 0;
}
```

When I try it, the first Instance with the name Jeff is correct, but the second Instance is already wrong.

I think it has to do with the fact that I mix the parsing with the getline function and the >> operator, but I don't know how I can go around that problem, because the second instance has a double name with a space in between and using just the >> operator would not work with that.

I would really appreciate any insight as I have spent way too much time with this problem now!

Comment: If you have line-based input, use `getline`.  At the most basic quick glance, you're only using this once, and then using formatted stream input for the other lines.  That will leave a newline in the stream.  Better to call `getline` a second time and then use a `std::istringstream` for formatted input from that line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you suspect, the formatted input is leaving behind newlines in the stream.  A convoluted approach is to use `istream::ignore` or `std::ws` to eat that up, but it's a bit untidy (and the latter may have change behavior if you need to read leading spaces on the next line).

Plus, it's not as clear as simply using `std::getline` to begin with.  Announce your intentions for input to be line-based by using line-based reads.

Consider an approach like this (using `<sstream>`):

```
std::string line1, line2;
if (std::getline(istr, line1) && std::getline(istr, line2))
{
    std::cout << "Line 1: " << line1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Line 2: " << line2 << "\n";

    std::istringstream iss(line2);
    int i1, i2;
    std::string s2;
    if (iss >> i1 >> i2 >> s2)
    {
        std::cout << "Values: i1=" << i1 << " i2=" << i2 << " s2=" << s2 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.  Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for a bit more information on how this website works, and [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).